# How to perform functions with multiple NSButtons in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, nsbutton

I currently have 18 check-type switches as NSButtons in Swift. What I am trying to do is get them all to NSOnState. Instead of doing

```
switch1.state = NSOnState
```

each time, I want to do something along the lines of this:

```
let Switches: [NSButton] = [Switch1, Switch2, Switch3, Switch4, Switch5, Switch6, Switch7, Switch8, Switch9, Switch10, Switch11, Switch12, Switch13, Switch14, Switch15, Switch16, Switch17, Switch18]
Switches[0-17].state = NSOnState
```

The issue with this is that I don't know how to perform the second line properly. It is showing he the error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Any solutions or suggestions will help, thanks!

(Please note I don't know Objective-C, only Swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` is what you are looking for

```
switches.forEach{ $0.state = NSOnState }
```

By the way: Variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.